# loading a file in Python. Make string raw

Tags: python, load

I would like to load a file in Python using a certain package.

The load function of the package needs to know the filename (+ extension) and location. Like this:

```
package.load(os.path.join(my_directory_name, r'my_filename.xml'))
```

My situation is that I get the filename out of a pandas dataframe. I then add the correct extension, which is xml and I then try to load the file.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

package.load(os.path.join(directory_name, df['filename'] + '.xml'))
```

I get an error: No such file in directory.

The problem is that the r is not there. It should be in front of the string. How to I make the string df['filename] + '.xml' raw? Python is interpreting backslashes as special characters, but I want them to mean actual backslashes.

Comment: You missed a single quote after `df['filename`, is it a typo?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Thanks.

Comment: Can you put an example? What is the value of `directory_name` and `df['filename']` that is not working?

Comment: i sugest you print the result of `os.path.join(...)` and post here

Comment: for example: directory_name = 'C:\Documents' and df['filename'] = 'overviewdata'. These are just strings. The code works when you write: package.load(os.path.join( 'C:\Documents' , r'overviewdata.xml'))

Comment: It is the missing of the r in front of the filename that causes the error. How can I do this operation in my situation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169346/discussion-between-dslima90-and-marnix).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work

```
package.load(os.path.join(directory_name, repr(df['filename'] + '.xml')))
```

Comment: This doesn't work. repr() just seems to add quotes around df['filename'] + '.xml'. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
escape_dict = {'\'': r'\'', '\"': r'\"'}

def _raw(text):
    """Returns a raw string representation of text"""
    new_string = ''
    for char in text:
        try:
            new_string += escape_dict[char]
        except KeyError:
            new_string += char
    return new_string
```

If you now put _raw(my_string), it will work.